# Cypress: configure hardcoded user for api requests with cypress-ntlm-auth proxy

Tags: authentication, cypress, ntlm, negotiate

I'm using `cypress-ntlm-auth` plugin in my cypress automation project, providing me windows authentication (Ntlm, kerberos etc.)

In particular, I use the `ntlmSso` option for Negotiate with my app. If the server sends an authentication challenge, the ntlm-proxy will perform a NTLM or Negotiate login handshake with the credentials of the user running the test client.

The problem is that I need to use a pre-defined user (to be used in my pre-prod environment) to make api requests, instead of the logged on user on the computer.

How can I do that? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The `cypress-ntlm-auth` library allows you to specify this with `cy.ntlm()`, by passing in hosts, username, password, and domain.

```
cy.ntlm(["my.host.com"], "myUser", "myPass", "myDomain")
```

[Check out the docs here.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-ntlm-auth#usage) Take note of their strategy on storing passwords.